# Get a window from a raster in rasterio using coordinates instead of row/column offsets, width and height

Tags: rasterio

I am trying to open a windowed dataset in rasterio, but I have a bounding box to work with. I thought it would be easy to do this but it seems that it involves some complicated process with a "Mixin", something I am having a very hard time understanding, even after reading the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful).

The [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.windows.html) says:

> A subclass with this mixin MUST provide the following properties:
>   transform, height and width

But I don't know how I can implement these properties if I don't know ahead of time what the height and width are going to be, and I'm not even sure that I am implementing the code properly anyway. This is what I have so far:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import WindowMethodsMixin, Window
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

class MyWindow(WindowMethodsMixin, Window):
    pass

with rasterio.open("flask/Docker/app/dem/slope_sm.tif") as src:
    rst1 = src.read(1, window=MyWindow.window(...))
```

I know this is hardly complete but I am really confused about how to proceed.

My IDE tells me that the call to `MyWindow.window()` takes the following parameters:

1. self
2. left
3. bottom
4. right
5. top
6. precision (optional)

But I don't know what to pass to the "self" parameter. The rest of the parameters are understandable - they are the edges of my bounding box from which I am constructing the window.

The documentation doesn't supply any working example of this, which I find odd because this seems to me like a pretty typical operation.

Can somebody please show me how to do this, or at least explain what I am missing here?

Comment: [Rasterio:[Windowed reading and writing](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/windowed-rw.html)

Comment: @gene that link doesn't cover the getting a window from coordinates issue the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [`rasterio.windows.from_bounds`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.windows.html?highlight=bounds#rasterio.windows.from_bounds) function. No need for a class or mixin.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds


with rasterio.open(filepath) as src:
    rst = src.read(1, window=from_bounds(left, bottom, right, top, src.transform))
```

Comment: That is it, thank you, I don't know how I missed this. I knew it could not be the case that such a simple typical operation wouldn't have a built-in function for it.