# Change in altitude value after resizing .tif file

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, rasterio, python-imaging-library

I have a TIFF file of 7378x6923 (widthXheight) resolution. I resized it to 1200x1200 pixels using [Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) module in Python.

```
img = Image.open('path to tif file')
img = img.resize((1200,1200))
```

But after resizing, the pixel values show unusual values. Before resizing, a certain pixel's value was 125.28. Now, after resizing, that pixel's value has turned to 1123715645. I am reading the pixel value with:

```
with rasterio.open('path to tif file') as dataset:
    band = dataset.read(1)
    print(type(band))
    value_of_interest = band[row_of_interest, column_of_interest]
    print(value_of_interest)
```

Why does this happen?

How can I preserve the height values in same pixel position?

Comment: @user2856, I have added them.

Comment: @user2856, can I resize my image to some new size using resampling?

Comment: It shows that I can transform to certain sizes. But can I resize to any custom size? @user2856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pillow isn't a geospatial library, I recommend looking at [rasterio resampling](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html)

For example:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

# Register GDAL format drivers and configuration options with a
# context manager.
with rasterio.Env():

    with rasterio.open('/path/to/input.tif') as dataset:
        data = dataset.read(1, out_shape=(1200, 1200), resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
        # scale image transform
        transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
            (dataset.height / data.shape[0]),  # rows
            (dataset.width / data.shape[1])  # cols
        )

        profile = dataset.profile
        profile.update(transform=transform, width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[0])

    with rasterio.open('/path/to/output.tif', 'w', **profile) as dataset:
        dataset.write(data, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah see edit, I fixed a bug

Comment: you updated the width and height in profile.update? @user2856

Comment: `transform.scale`

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but do you know how to crop a specific part of a tif image? @user2856

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/336903/2856