# Change in Altitude Value of .tif file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I have a tif file of 7378 X 6923(widthXheight) resolution. I resized it to 1200 X 1200 pixels using Image class in python.

```
 img = Image.open('path to tif file')
 img = img.resize((1200,1200))
```

But after resizing, the pixel values show unusual values. Before resizing, a certain pixel's value was 125.28. Now, after resizing, that pixel's value has turned to 1123715645. I am reading the pixel value with:

```
with rasterio.open('path to tif file') as dataset:
    band = dataset.read(1)
    print(type(band))
    value_of_interest = band[row_of_interest, column_of_interest]
    print(value_of_interest)
```

Why does this happen?

How can I preserve the height values in same pixel position?

Comment: I'd susggest editing your [original question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348095/change-in-altitude-value-after-resizing-tif-file) and voting to reopen it instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: How do I vote to reopen the question? @MarceloVilla